# GNUkhata accounting system installation

Tags: frameworks, localhost, installation, pyramid, accounting

Any python web developer help me and explain how to install GNUKhata Accounting system on localhost using pyramid web framework i tried to run gkcore gkweb folders but it's not runing how i can run the project files and activate on localhost   .. Thanking all so much

Comment: What did you try to install it? What error messages do you see? Without that information, no one can help. I suggest you contact the vendor for support: https://support.gnukhata.in/ Otherwise I assume you install it like any other Python project. I could not find any documentation for GNUKhata.

Comment: how ti install like any other python project ... i need help please

Comment: What have you tried? You need to give more information for anyone to help you.

Comment: i want to understand the steps how to run the application using python language on localhost on windows.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the vendor for support for their product? That would be the first thing to do.

Comment: i tried sure but they are not helping just saying contact the support for service

Comment: OK, you tried the first step. What other things have you tried, if any? Honestly I don't know where to start to help you. Help me to help you by saying what you have tried. That's how Stack Overflow and any support works. Do you have Python installed? Do you know how to install a Python package? Do you know how to create a Python virtual environment? Please respect our time by telling us what you know and don't know.

Comment: I found a installation guide in their gitlab wiki page. See if it helps. https://gitlab.com/gnukhata/gkwebapp/-/wikis/home